# Ember.observer run on init

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm attempting to build an Ember app without prototype extensions and the Ember docs give examples of how to do this, but they don't include the example of when I want my observer to run on init. 
So currently if my code were written like this:

```
fullNameChanged: function() {
   // deal with the change
}.observes('fullName').on('init')
```

The only example I can find to write it is like this:

```
Person.reopen({
  fullNameChanged: Ember.observer('fullName', function() {
    // deal with the change
  })
});
```

So how would I tell this code to run on init?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

May be you are looking for this

```
Person.reopen({
    fullNameChanged: Ember.on('init', Ember.observer('fullName', function () {
        // deal with the change
    }))
});
```

OR (*this won't fire handler if change happens on `init`, use above on that case*)

```
Person.reopen({
  init: function(){
    Ember.observer('fullName', function() {
      // deal with the change
    });
  }
});
```

**Alright, this edit for answer the mistakes(?) mentioned below**

1. Well, sometimes it might be necessary to [fire the observer on initialization time](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/object-model/observers/#toc_observers-and-object-initialization).
2. [`Ember.observer`](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_observer) is an `Ember` namespace method, not part of [`Ember.Object`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html)'s prototype. Therefore `this.observer` never exists, but [`addObserver()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_addObserver) does.
3. There is no need to invoke the handler, Ember runtime will invoke the handler when the property changes
4. calling `this._super` is unnecessary unless it really does matter. In this case, if `Person` just extends `Ember.Object` calling super doesn't do anything.

   > By default, does nothing unless it is overridden during class definition.
5. It's contextual, and as long as OP didn't specify anything about class definition it's beyond the scope of answering.

[**Nothing better explains than an example**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rapuqetusi/2/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer actually contains five separate mistakes, of varying degrees of severity.

1. It unnecessarily places setting up the observer in the init hook.
2. It sets up the observer inside the `init` hook incorrectly, using `Ember.observer` instead of `this.observer`, which won't even work.
3. It fails to invoke (as opposed to setting up) the handler at init time.
4. It fails to call `init` on the superclass.
5. It unnecessarily uses `reopen`.

#### 1. No need to set up observer in `init` hook

You do not need any procedural "call" or "invocation" in an init hook to set up an observer. Either of the two following forms will set them up automatically when the object is instantiated.

```
fullNameChanged:        function() { } . observes('fullName')
observeFullNameChanged: Ember.observer('fullName', this.fullNameChanged.bind(this))
```

#### 2. Use `object.observer` for procedural setup of observers.

If you **did** want to set up the observer procedurally, then you call `object.observer`, not `Ember.observer`, which is defined for use as above. Calling `Ember.observer` procedurally will accomplish nothing; Ember will have no idea of what object the property to observe lies. In this case, it would be `this.observer('fullName', ...)` (although as mentioned above you actually don't need to do this at all; instead use the approach of point 1).

#### 3. Invoke handler on `init`

But you also want to **invoke** the handler at `init` time. There are three ways:

```
init:                function() { this.fullNameChanged(); /* call super */ }
initFullNameChanged: Ember.on('init', this.fullNameChanged.bind(this))
fullNameChanged:     function() { ... }.on('init')
```

where the third option uses the prototype extensions you don't want.

#### 4. Calling `super` from `init`

If you are going to have an `init` hook, even though it's not needed, you need to call `super`, or things will break down horribly:

```
init: function() {
  ...
  this._super.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

#### 5 No need for `reopen`

`reopen` accomplishes nothing here. Just put the above properties into the class definition itself.

### Solution

The correct answer to what is the equivalent of

```
fullNameChanged: function observer() { }.observes('fullName').on('init')
```

is therefore

```
fullNameChanged:        function() { },
observeFullNameChanged: Ember.observer('fullName', this.fullNameChanged.bind(this)),
initFullNameChanged:    Ember.on('init', this.fullNameChanged.bind(this))
```

It would be equivalent, and possibly more readable, to do this:

```
initFullNameChanged: Ember.on('init', function() {

  // define and execute handler
  (function fullNameChanged() { ... }());

  // set up obsever
   this.observe('fullName, fullNameChanged);
})
```